# Progress indicator in a batch file while tracert runs

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file

I have a batch file that runs fairly quickly, BUT there are a couple tracer's that take forever to run.  I want to find a way to show that something is happening (NOT showing the tracert results though) while it runs...  Doesn't have to show a percentage or anything...  Even just a spinner ( /-\| ) in an overwriting, single character or just a series of "."'s that keeps getting longer.  The trick though is that the batch file needs to basically run both of these at the same time, then the progress indicator ends when the tracert finishes.

I saw this one:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711188/batch-file-progress-spinning-wheel, but it seems to only update between commands (NOT multiple updates while a single command is still running).

I also want this to be the main batch file, not a separate file (nor using any 3rd party tools that are not already in Server 2003 or higher).

Could be nice, but doubt really possible...  Show a more finite progress based on the current hop that tracert is on  (IE:  1/15, 2/15, 3/15).  (Not needed for an accepted answer, but would give you more Super Answerer status to me...  ;)

Comment: Oh, and I would want the progress to be on one line (unless it wraps due to long running), not just a few characters on a line, with each update being on a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Assumming there is some kind of log where everything is being written
    set "logFile=output.txt"

    rem Variables we need
    rem .... a variable containing a carriage return for spinner output
    for /f %%a in ('copy "%~f0" nul /z') do set "CR=%%a"

    rem .... a lock file to be used as a indicator of file being written
    rem      we can use the same log file, but included just to handle the
    rem      case where there is no log file
    set "lockFile=%temp%\%~nx0.%random%%random%.lock"

    rem .... the spinner to show
    set "spin=/-\|"

    (   
        9>"%lockFile%" tracert 10.1.1.1 >> "%logFile%"
    ) | <nul >nul 2>&1 ( 
        cmd /v /q /c "for /l %%a in (0) do ( ping -n 2 localhost & set "spin=!spin:~1!!spin:~0,1!" & (( type nul >>"%lockFile%" )&&( del /q "%lockFile%" & exit )||( set /p"=Waiting !spin:~0,1!!CR!" >con  )))"
    )
```

For a step by step explanation (same code, just splitted for better screen reading)

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Assumming there is some kind of log where everything is being written
    set "logFile=output.txt"


    rem Variables we need
    rem .... a variable containing a carriage return for spinner output
    for /f %%a in ('copy "%~f0" nul /z') do set "CR=%%a"

    rem .... a lock file to be used as a indicator of file being written
    rem      we can use the same log file, but included just to handle the
    rem      case where there is no log file
    set "lockFile=%temp%\%~nx0.%random%%random%.lock"

    rem .... the spinner to show
    set "spin=/-\|"

    rem .... This set of variables just hold the code that will be used
    rem      for each of the steps. They can be removed and placed directly
    rem      in the code below, but as the same will be done by the parser
    rem      this will make documentation easier

    rem .... How we will wait forever until the traceroute process ends
    set "loop= for /l %%a in (0) do "

    rem .... How to include a wait state to save cpu.
    set "wait= ping -n 2 localhost "

    rem .... How to rotate the spinner to later show the correct element
    set "rotateSpin= set "spin=!spin:~1!!spin:~0,1!" "

    rem .... How to show the progress if the tracert is still working
    set "progress= set /p"=Waiting !spin:~0,1!!CR!" >con "

    rem .... How to check if the tracert has ended: Just try to append 
    rem      nothing to the lock file 
    set "check= type nul >>"%lockFile%" "

    rem .... What to do when the traceroute ends. To use the log file
    rem      insted of the generated lock, remember to remove the del
    rem      command, we do not want to delete the log
    set "atEnd= del /q "%lockFile%" & exit "

    rem And here everything is joined. The content of the variables is 
    rem replaced by the parser, generating the final command.

    rem A pipe is generated. The left part of the pipe (the generator)
    rem is the traceroute command, and the right part (the consumer) 
    rem is the code that will generate the spinner.

    rem The lock is hold by redirection of one of the user handles
    rem (here the handle 9 is used) if the left part of the pipe.
    rem When the traceroute command ends, the handle is released.

    rem The right part of the pipe just loops checking if the lock is 
    rem released and echoing the spinner if it has not. This code
    rem runs in a separate cmd instance.

    (   
        9>"%lockFile%" tracert 10.1.1.1 >> "%logFile%"
    ) | <nul >nul 2>&1 ( 
        cmd /v /q /c "%loop% ( %wait% & %rotateSpin% & (( %check% )&&( %atEnd% )||( %progress% )))"
    )
```

Comment: ABSOLUTELY perfect!!!  Thank you!  Only way it could be better is if it didn't have a file that it used, but to get this to work, I'm perfectly happy with your solution!!!  Kudos on the scripting comments too!

Comment: One last thing...  Trying to get the "Waiting" line to change to "Waiting...  Done!" once complete, how can I do that?  I tried to put the following line after your part, but it prints it out exactly how I want it, but then just hangs there and doesn't go on to the next command...

Comment: Oops, can't do normal here...  Here's the code:  `set /p"=Tracerouting... DONE!" >con`

Comment: @BondUniverse, `set "atEnd= del /q "%lockFile%" & echo Tracerouting... DONE! >con & exit "`

Comment: I can't seem to get that in the right place of the code...  Where should it go?

Comment: @BondUniverse, It replaces the same `set` line in the second code. For the first one, change `( del /q "%lockFile%" & exit )` into `(del /q "%lockFile%" & echo Tracerouting... DONE! >con & exit )`